# Firebase updateDoc function not working Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to update my document on firestore, i'm able to get the data and prefill it in the placholder but i'm having issues with updating the data with updateDoc.

I have tried to print out the values and it is still the same data and nothing changes within the code. My firebase version is 10.7.2.

```
 
 function EditTodo({ setTodo, todo }) {
   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");
 
   const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
   const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

   const handleUpdate = async () => {
     //   e.preventDefault()
     const docRef = doc(db, "todos",todo.id);
     try {
       await updateDoc(docRef, {
         todo: todo.todo,
         date: todo.date,
       });

       window.location.reload();
     } catch (err) {
       alert(err);
     }
   };

   return (
     <>
       <i
         className="fa fa-pencil fa-1x rounded-circle border  border-primary p-2"
         aria-hidden="true"
         onClick={handleShow}
       ></i>

       <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
         <Modal.Header closeButton>
           <Modal.Title>Todo Name: {todo.todo}</Modal.Title>
         </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Body>
           <Form.Label>Todo</Form.Label>
           <Form.Control
             required
             type="text"
             className="input"
             placeholder={todo.id}
           />
           <Form.Control
             required
             type="text"
             className="input"
             placeholder={todo.todo}
             onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
           />
           <Form.Control
             required
             type="date"
             className="input my-2"
             placeholder={todo.date}
             onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
           />
         </Modal.Body>
         <Modal.Footer>
           <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
             Close
           </Button>
           <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleUpdate}>
             Save Changes
           </Button>
         </Modal.Footer>
       </Modal>
     </>
   );
 }

export default EditTodo;
```